# string + operation error?

Tags: java, string, operation

So I made a simple program following the curriculum in Think Java. I was able to successfully make the code they asked for. But I encountered an error. When I add the operation at the end of the string, I get a different number than if I put the operation on its own line. Can anyone explain why? Where is that number in the last line of code coming from exactly?

Thank you, everyone!

```
public class Time{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int hour=14;
    int minute=22;
    System.out.print("The number of seconds since midnight is: ");
    System.out.println((hour*60*60)+(minute*60));
    System.out.println("The number of seconds since midnight is: "+(hour*60*60)+(minute*60));


}}
```

**Thank you so much, Nongthonbam Tonthoi and everyone else (and those who directed me to the duplicate question). I probably wouldn't have found the answer because I didn't even know that was the same issue. Now I do though; I learned a lot from combining these responses. I really appreciate it.

Comment: `+` is string concatenation, as well as addition. You're not very clear which you want in the third `println`, and probably getting concatenations where you want to get addition.

Comment: The last `println` statement, the number will be added to `String`, hence turning all of that expression to `String` and the result of last parentheses will be added to that `String` as well.

Comment: `"a" + 1 + 1` doesn't give `"a" + 2`, it gives `"a11"`.

Comment: Enclose the last part in brackets

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
System.out.println("The number of seconds since midnight is: "+(hour*60*60)+(minute*60));
```

to:

```
System.out.println("The number of seconds since midnight is: "+ ((hour*60*60)+(minute*60)));
```

Add extra brackets.